# Call a function in an array foreach loop with nested data

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, foreach

The following obviously doesn't work but it is the goal I am trying to reach:

```
items.forEach(addData(item.data));
```

I know I can do:

```
items.forEach(function(item){
    addData(item.data)
});
```

but I was wondering if there was a shorthand / cooler way of doing this.

edit:

I am also calling the same add data function with an array of items that
aren't nested like so:

```
items.forEach(addItemId)
```

Which is why I was trying to find a way to use the same function (in a similar) fashion for the nested object.

Comment: Lambda? `items.forEach(item => addData(item.data));`

Comment: I don't think there's any shorthand in regular Javascript. Libraries like underscore.js and lodash probably have ways to do it.

Comment: iirc cant you bind the function argument to a function @Barmar?

Comment: @SterlingArcher How would that automatically get the `.data` property of every element of the array?

Comment: You could adjust the `addData` function to look for `.data` :P

Comment: You can obviously rewrite the function or define a new intermediary function, but that doesn't generalize.

Comment: `item =>` is just shorthand for `function(item)`

Comment: if you learn how to use underscore.js, it will help with so many situations like this.  here is their [foreach loop](http://underscorejs.org/#each)

Comment: If only JavaScript had functional composition :(

Answer (score 1):

Use an ES6 feature: Lambdas.

```
items.forEach(item => addData(item.data));
```

I'm trying to find a way to use `.bind` here, but to be honest, this is a pretty clean way. One liner, shorthand for `function() { }`.

Comment: How about a little `items.forEach(({ data }) => addData(data));`

Comment: Is that fancy destructuring I see?

Comment: Thats right. Whats the point of programming if you don't get to make yourself feel clever? haha

Answer (score 0):

If you can update your function to use `item` instead of `item.data` you could do this:

```
items.forEach(addData);
```

This will call addData with each `item`, not `item.data` though

Comment: While this is true, Barmar had a good point that this doesn't generalize the solution. OP might not want to do that and is looking for a way to bind the item.data param, not item

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily recommend doing this in production code, but you can accomplish something like this with a little combinator:

```
const map_into = k => fn => o => fn(o[k]);

items.forEach(map_into('data')(addData));
```